# How to use absolute references in google sheets query formula or query by column names for multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, subquery

I have the following problem. I'm trying to write query formula in order to put all values in one sheet by typing yes in one column, however, I have the following problem. Whenever I add a new column, references in query formula (multiple sheets) are changing and the formula doesn't work. How can I prevent this?

Or is there any way to query by a column name in multiple sheets?

I have tried locking relative references by putting sign $
I have tried to use an indirect formula to take references (data set in Helper TAB, cell E2) - nothing worked

I'm out of the ideas, for now, anyone knows how to fix this?

```
=QUERY({'Sheet 1'!$A:$Z;'Sheet 2'!$A:$Z;'Sheet 3'!$A:$Z;'Sheet 4'!$A:$Z}, "select * where Col1 ='yes'",0)
```

Here is the file I did, you can see query formula in Master sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XD-CECy5W5-HM5EkBFJQKDtLlykQq8Cj8ZOvDUXkd1s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, no one helped, I have tried too, but without any progress.

Comment: try: `=QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A:Z;'Sheet 2'!A:Z;'Sheet 3'!A:Z;'Sheet 4'!A:Z}, "where Col1 ='yes'",0)`

Comment: Didn't work, actually, have the same formula. Every time i add new columns to sheets, ranges in data set automatically change...

Comment: try: `=QUERY({INDIRECT("'Sheet 1'!A:Z");INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!A:Z");INDIRECT("'Sheet 3'!A:Z");INDIRECT("'Sheet 4'!A:Z")}, "where Col1 ='yes'",0)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem is to use a formula that searches for the column address based on a reference.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN(A1);4);"1";"")
```

This formula will return the value **A**, which is the column of address **A1**.
It can be used in query functions like this:

```
=QUERY(A:D;"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN(A1);4);"1";"")&"")
```

This function is equivalent to the function:

```
=QUERY(A:D;"SELECT A")
```